# How to parse and fetch XML sitemap nutch

Tags: xml, web-crawler, sitemap, nutch

When Nutch fetches a sitemap, it does not go ahead fetch all the links in the  tag in the sitemap.

What configuration option do I set to make nutch crawl and fetch all the links mentioned in the sitemap.

Comment: I found this link on the Nutch Wiki https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/SitemapFeature

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [nutch issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1741).

There is a working for nutch sitemap parser [here](https://github.com/cguzel/nutch-sitemapCrawler)